# The process cannot access file due to opened already

Tags: c#

The code running on wince 5.0 / .net framework compact 2.0
Always get a exception says:

> *the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.*

Really confused as i already encolse the stream in the using statement,so the filestream should be closed automaticly once leave the using block .

```
//read text
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fname))
{
  string line;
  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    // append into stringbuilder
    sb.Append(line);
    sb.Append("\n");
  }
}
//write text, below code raise the exception. 
//if i comment it and re-run the code,exception disappear
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fname))
{
  sw.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

addition:i just want to update the file, read and write. any better way?

Comment: What if you add a breakpoint before your StreamWriter and try to manually edit the file? Just to check if it maybe some permission error.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in your code. Could it be that another process (beside your application) works with this file?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the using statement only guarantees that the reader will be disposed of, but not that it's disposed of before the next using statement.  Unless you call Close() you don't have control over when the file is closed.

Comment: make sure that the file is not already opened. ?

Comment: Where is fname located? It looks to be a permission-issue.

Comment: @jmstoker `Dispose` closes stream as you can see from the code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#011147a163b10458

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Fair enough, thanks for sharing that.  I did some searching in other SO posts after I made that comment, and they have the same consensus.

Comment: @Allan S. Hansen because debug cant be do due to deploy issue. anyway,will definitely try it.

Comment: @Tomtom maybe not due to this as i commented the write snippet , exception disappeared.

Comment: Something which could also be tried; try to add a thread sleep or something in between the usings - say 5-10 seconds - to see if it might be slow I/O.

Comment: @Allan S. Hansen. thanks, care to advise how to wait a while for file closure?

Comment: Does it work, if you comment out the read and only do some writing on this file?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code on my computer. There is no problem.

Better way. For read and write full file, you can use `File.ReadAllText(fname)` and `File.WriteAllText(fname)`. And instead of using `\n` use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText` are not supported in .Net **Compact** Framework - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file_methods%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: thanks. i also created a windows form app based on the same code and it runs without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, the issue is in my code and i confused you here as i dont share that code.
actually because i wrote this in the very beginning of the program

```
// f is the fileinfo which point to fname as well
string text = f.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
```

this created a streamreader, not being assigned to any varible, but it's in the heap.so i ignored.
thanks people helpping here. BTW changed code to this then issue gone

```
using (StreamReader sr = f.OpenText())
{
   string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```